# Kubernetes cluster shared storage and backup solutions

Tags: backup, kubernetes, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage, architecture

Which shared storage solutions are common for Kubernetes cluster to implement shared storage persistence for containers? NFS on NAS / iSCSI somehow?
How do you backup the data on a Kubernetes with this type of storage?

Answer (score 5):

It’s the same storage you use as a backend for your running virtual machines, say NFSv3/v4, iSCSI and FC. Concepts behind are very similar.

You might want to read the Docker/Kubernetes backup overview here:

https://www.networkworld.com/article/3514560/how-to-back-up-kubernetes-and-docker.amp.html

It won’t be acceptable by ServerFault to recommend any particular product as its opinion-based answer, obviously.

Comment: So iSCSI is less recommended? Kubernetes documentation says no simultaneous writers allowed. Which type of storage is commonly used?

Answer (score -1):

It depends upon you environment (public cloud Vs. on premises).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/